# Is it possible to target a specific .NET Framework Version or Profile using command line without a VS solution or project file?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, command-prompt

I am trying to target the full .NET 4.0, as described here, because the default seems to target the client profile:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2009/10/19/what-s-new-in-net-framework-4-client-profile-beta-2.aspx

I also see instructions here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

But I am wondering whether there's a flag or combination of flags I can pass to csc.exe to target the full framework without using Visual Studio. More specific, I'd like to avoid solutions that require creating a solution or project file.

Comment: Why do you want to call csc.exe directly? If you kindly switch to MSBuild.exe, you will see a lot of properties you can set via command line which makes more sense.

Comment: I'm on a system using Makefiles currently.

Comment: Not sure what kind of makefile system you use, but calling MSBuild inside NAnt or another build system is a typical practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, target framework just specifies where to look the types in and what types to look for. So, as long as you use only the types defined in the .NET version you want, it will be compatible with that version's runtime compiled without any additional options.

Comment: The C# compiler does not target the full framework, and as a result, I get this when I try to compile: The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Which is in System.Web.dll, not available in the client profile.